# Запуск задачи на Sun Grid Engine

Tags: oracle, ubuntu

Всем доброго времени суток, подскажите, как запустить задачу на Sun Grid Engine(SGE)? Настроил по мануалу, вроде все ок, а как запустить задачу, мануала нет. К примеру, есть файл pi.cpp, где на mpi рассчитывается число pi, как запустить данную задачу через SGE, хотя бы локально?

Answer (score 2):

Первым делом программу нужно откомпилировать.

Но прежде - одно замечание относительно статуса SGE после поглощения компании Sun компанией Oracle. В результате поглощения код Sun Grid Engine стал достоянием сообщества. Основанный на нём продукт Oracle Grid Engine можно загрузить с сайта Oracle. Наиболее активным независимым проектом на основе этого кода является [Son of Grid Engine](https://arc.liv.ac.uk/trac/SGE), который поддерживается Ливерпульским университетом.

Последовательность действий примерно такова:

1. Установить инструменты для разработки MPI-программ. Можно установить MPICH2 или OpenMPI. В дистрибутиве Ubuntu можно установить метапакеты `mpich2` или `openmpi-bin` и `openmpi-dev`
2. Откомпилировать программу командой `mpicxx -O2 pi.cpp -o pi`
3. Запустить программу командой `mpiexec -n 2 ./pi`

Так мы убедимся, что инструменты для разработки MPI-программ установлены. Теперь можно установить Grid Engine. В Ubuntu есть пакеты `gridengine-master`, `gridengine-client` и `gridengine-exec`, которые нужно установить, соответственно на головной узел кластера, узлы, с которых будут отправляться задания, и узлы, на которых будут выполняться расчеты

1. Установим сразу всё на один компьютер `sudo apt-get install gridengine-master gridengine-client gridengine-exec`
2. Добавим этот компьютер в список компьютеров, с которых будут отправляться задания`sudo qconf -as mypchostname`
3. Создадим список пользователей и добавить в него себя `sudo qconf -au myname newuserlist`
4. Создадим очередь задач `sudo qconf -aq all.q` указать в настройках очереди по-крайней мере параметры `hostlist` и `newuserlist` в разделе `user_lists`.
5. Подготовим сценарий запуска программы `pi.run` примерно такого содержания:``` #!/bin/csh``mpiexec -n 2 ./pi ```
6. Поставим сценарий в очередь задач командой `qsub pi.run`
7. Посмотрим, попала ли задача в очередь `qstat`
8. Если всё сделано правильно, то вскоре появятся файлы `pi.run.e1` и `pi.run.o1`. В последнем файле будет содержаться вывод расчетной программы.

Если что-то пойдет не так, инструкции придется искать в многочисленных мануалах. Например, на сайте Oracle или в каталоге [HOWTO](http://arc.liv.ac.uk/SGE/howto/howto.html).